# Keeping the child node's position relative to that of its jQuery resizable-enabled parent?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

Is it possible to keep the position of `<p>`children relative to their jQuery resizable parents?

Sorry if my wording is a little confusing.

You can see it in action [here](http://www.tiletabs.com).

What I want to have happen, is when those "tiles" are dragged into a different shape, have the `<p>` elements stay in the bottom-left corner of the tiles.

Is it possible to accomplish this with pure CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can achieve this by simply setting:

```
.tile p {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}
```

in the CSS for those paragraphs.

Comment: Thanks!  OK, because having those set to `position: absolute` "binds" them to my "tile" `<div>`'s because those `<div>`'s have their position set to `relative`, not `static`.  I completely forgot about this xD